# DataContract not available at WCF client service reference

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, datacontract

I have this Data contract in my WCF service

```
[DataContract]
public class Department
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Section
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Room
{
    [DataMember]
    public uint RoomId { get; set; }
}
```

When I reference my service in client application,I only see Room class,Can any body explain me why contract for Department and Section class are not available at client side.

Comment: Have you reloaded your service? I'm almost sure you have referenced older version of your service which does not have `Section` and `Department` classes. You need to publish your newest version of service and then reload reference in other project.

Comment: Yes I have tried with updated service reference,still I only get Room class.The only difference I see is that Room class has native types but others have user defined ones.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx try KnownTypes from here

Comment: I used KnownType tag just below Datacontract attribute of Department and Section Class,but still nothing appears at client side.I tried using a dummy operation contract in my Service interface which returns these user defined types then I can see the definition of these types at client side.Is it necessary to have an operation contract for user defined class in order to see them at client side?

Comment: @TRS - that's a good question; it might be, since unused data contracts may not be considered part of the metadata.  I'd suggest adding some operations that use the other Data Contracts and see what happens.

Answer (score 16):

In your `ServiceContract` interface add one single operation related to `Department` which will make `Department` and `Section` visible to your client application.

Since Department contains list of Sections, it will expose Section as well.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Room GetRoom();

    [OperationContract]
    List<Department> GetDepartments();
}
```

### Explanation

You can verify it by using [Svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

If no operation contract exist for user defined classes, its `definition won't emit in proxy class` generated using Svcutil.

If I omit second operation contract of `Department`, only `Room` class gets emitted in proxy class. So, you need to have atleast one operation contract on your class to make it visible to your client.

PROXY class for Room:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", 
                                                  "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Room", 
             Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DummyService")]
public partial class Room : object,
                System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{        
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;        
    private uint RoomIdField;        
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public uint RoomId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RoomIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RoomIdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any sources to back this up?

Comment: update: i tried this, and it really works. still some literature on the subject would be interesting.