# One of the DataContract classes doesn't generating on the client side by adding service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, datacontract

I have three `DataContract` classes in wcf service. I've added service reference to the client and two of my classes work great, but the third one hasn't appeared in service reference. I don't use this class in my service interface, can it be the reason of my problem? Here is this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Security
{
    public Security(){ }

    public string Sha1(string input)
    {
        byte[] hash;
        using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider Sha1Provider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            hash = Sha1Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in hash) sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

If it is important, I've added reference for `System.Security.Cryptography` to my client.

Comment: Can you provide a some of the Client code where this is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DataContract is not exposed in your ServiceContract, the client won't get the DataContract because it isn't needed.

A more robust explanation can be found on this question: [DataContract not available at WCF client service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286785/datacontract-not-available-at-wcf-client-service-reference)

Comment: Also, this class doesn't look like much of a DataContract.  It doesn't have any DataMembers defined.  It looks like you are trying to pass some shared logic to your client wrapped in a DataContract.

Comment: Okay, thank you, it is clear now. Actually, I just need this security class on the client and on the service, so I decided to share it like this instead of creating two same classes there. I think, I'll put this class to the dll now.